# How do I enable search for package with missing command

Tags: server, 16.04

On Ubuntu Server 14.04 when I type a command not currently installed, it will tell me which packages I can choose from to install. Here is an example of what that looks like:

```
# chromium-browser
The program 'chromium-browser' is currently not installed. You can install it by typing:
apt-get install chromium-browser
```

This feature was enabled by default. I didn't have to do anything myself to get such suggestions. Now if I do the same on a fresh install of Ubuntu Server 16.04, it looks like this:

```
# chromium-browser
bash: chromium-browser: command not found
```

What do I need to do on Ubuntu Server 16.04 to get the behavior I am used to from 14.04?

(In the above examples I used `chromium-browser` because it is a package I knew I hadn't installed on any of my servers. But it could be any package not installed by default.)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I found that what I had to do was to install the `command-not-found` package:

```
apt-get install command-not-found
```

After running this command and restarting the shell, I got the behavior I liked from earlier Ubuntu versions.